# Change drawable from widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

Cant change the android:background from my **widget_main.xml**

I have tryed

```
remoteviews.setInt(R.id.boton, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.toggle_on);
```

and

```
remoteviews.setImageViewResource(R.id.boton, R.drawable.toggle_on);
```

with no results.

Here is my **widget_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/boton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_off"/>
```

and my **onReceive** from my **AppWidgetProvider**:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
    if (intent.getAction().equals(WIDGET_BUTTON)) {         

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);          
        views.setInt(R.id.boton, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.toggle_on);
```

Comment: I guess you should iterate view one by one and set the proper image for every.

Comment: In onUpdate method it works, with iterate. But, i want to change the background image in OnReceive method.. how can iterate there? Thanks